# How to make ANT Task <java> show detailed error if failed?

Tags: java, ant

I'm using ANT to build app. But when the building is failed, it displays: 
Java returned: 1 
There is nothing more info so that it is hardly for me to debug what's going on.
The only thing I knew is the failure happened during executed a ANT tak .
So, I believe that an exception was thrown by the invoking method.

But how can I make ANT display the detail information once there is anything wrong during ANT  Task?

I do appreciate anyone's help!

Comment: For this reason you should use loggers.

Comment: This might not help in this case, but "ant -d ..." will show you more info on what it is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone.
Finally, I found the answer by myself.
The attribute "output" of `<java`> task can help on this case.
e.g. output="C:/buildError.log"

Answer (score 2):

Use the 'verbose' property of javac which is set to 'no' by default

```
<javac verbose = 'true' srcdir = "...">
```

Comment: but what the executed task is <java> not <javac>

Comment: You could use the output = 'filename' to specify a file to which the output is written. Error will also be written to the same file. Alternatively you could specify errors to be written to a different file using the error = 'filename'